# Color map from random raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay, colormap

I am trying to create a color map overlay of sound levels from a known source using QGIS (3.8). The results of the noise calculations come out as a raster in polar coordinates (NOT rectangular), centered around the source. The raster can output as a CSV file with the format of Lat, Long, Noise level as follows:

```
35.59, -82.55, 45.5
35.58, -82.56, 44.5
35.60, -82.54, 55.2
...
```

There must be something simple I am missing because all I seem able to do is display the individual raster points. I don't want to even see those. All I want to have plotted is a color map of the levels.

I have tried using the Raster->Conversion->Vector to Raster tool, but all I get are not particularly descriptive errors.

Comment: And you're working with... ?

Comment: Sorry! I meant to say I am working with QGIS.